# FFMPEG Trying to Process a Colored BG for a Transparent MOV and turn into an HTML5 MP4

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been trying for the last hour to take a MOV with transparency and combine it with a color background. This I can do with this command here:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -filter_complex "color=#f5a3a3,format=rgb24[c];[c][0]scale2ref[c][i];[c][i]overlay=format=auto:shortest=1,setsar=1" output.mp4
```

Problem is that that mp4 is unplayable as it is being formated to `yuv444`. I've tried to take the resulting mp4 and reencode to `yuv420p` using simple filters but I cannot seem to do it.

Thanks for any advice on this.

**WORKAROUND:**
I managed to workaround this by by moving from MOV to WEBM (which i needed anyway) and including the complex filter. Then I moved from WEBM to MP4 and all was good. Am still curious about original question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the format filter after overlay to convert it.

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -filter_complex "color=#f5a3a3,format=rgb24[c];[c][0]scale2ref[c][i];[c][i]overlay=format=auto:shortest=1,format=yuv420p,setsar=1" output.mp4`

Comment: Darn....that's it. Ha.  Thanks!  Worked!